# Odoo14, how to modify the default query conditions of search views in custom modules

Tags: odoo-14

I want to filter the current year's data when entering the contact module dashboard view.

I tried using custom components to add default search criteria, but it didn't take effect.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WdOw.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teipX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Search defaults](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/views.html#search-defaults)

> Search fields and filters can be configured through the action’s context using `search_default_name` keys. For fields, the value should be the value to set in the field, for filters it’s a boolean value or a number

You can find a similar example in the CRM module:

- Define a [filter](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/140e58c5a68db674fc1d240147e4d669b29f2cad/addons/crm/report/crm_opportunity_report_views.xml#L105) in the search view with a default period:

  ```
  <filter name="filter_create_date" date="create_date" default_period="this_year"/>
  ```
- Use the filter in the [action context](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/140e58c5a68db674fc1d240147e4d669b29f2cad/addons/crm/views/crm_team_views.xml#L113C13-L117C64):

  ```
  <field name="context">{
            ...
            'search_default_filter_create_date': 1}</field>
  ```